# Rolling mean with start date happens before

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

this code gives me the rolling mean from 90d before up to today
`df.rolling('90d', on='Date')['quantity'].mean()`
what I want now is from 90d before up to 30d before, how to achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

I would roll twice with `sum` and `count`:

```
roll90 = df.rolling('90d').quantity.agg({'sum','count'})

# you may want roll29 instead of roll30
roll30 = df.rolling('30d').quantity.agg({'sum','count'})

roll = roll90 - roll30

roll['mean'] = roll['sum']/roll['count']
```